# setNeedsDisplay not fast enough (what's the right way to do this?)

Tags: macos, cocoa, drawing

I'm trying to make a very simple paint application (Cocoa). In my custom view I have my drawRect: method, which creates a rectangle at the cursor location:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect{
NSPoint point = [self.window mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream];
NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(point.x, point.y, 5, 5)); }
```

and I also implemented mouseDown: and mouseDragged:, both of which tell the view to redraw the area  drawRect: will fill.

```
     NSPoint point = [self.window mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream];
[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:NSMakeRect(point.x,point.y,5,5)];
```

However, if I move my cursor even moderately fast, there are gaps between the drawn objects. Also, if new rectangles are drawn over the old ones, a white border will show. I have thus concluded that I must be using the wrong set of tools. How do I get rects to appear at the mouse XY as it moves across the view, in real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your must be referring to rectangles being drawn with some distance from each other, i.e. not consecutively every pixel, when you move the mouse fast enough.

Well, I would guess that this is standard behaviour due to the mouse pointer actually skipping some positions along it's path of movement on screen. In other words, mouse pointer does not go through every pixel on screen when moving fast.

*(Edit: Reason for that is quite obvious: the mouse has a fixed tracking frequency; as such on sudden, swift movements of the mouse, tracking points are coarser)*

Nothing to do about that I'm afraid, you will have to create the interpolation of rectangles yourself along the pointer path. Store the previous mouse position and draw a shape that interpolated between the old and the new position. Like so:

[image]